# How can I get the output as 'str' instead of <class 'str'> when I check the string type in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

When I check the type of the data,
I am trying to get the output as 'str' instead of <class 'str'>, Any suggestions would help.

Input:

```
a="Hello"
print(type(a))
```

Output:

```
<class 'str'>
```

Expected:

```
str
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `__name__` property:

```py
>>>  type("test").__name__
'str'
```

However, if you want to check if an object is a string or not, you're better of using `isinstance`:

```py
>>> isinstance("test", str)
True
```

Answer (score 0):

One uses usually `isinstance(...)` as in

```
a = "Hello"
if isinstance(a, str):
    # do sth. then
```